# Interrupt Vector. Location / Who sets it?

Tags: operating-system, interrupt

Knowing that An interrupt vector is the memory address of an interrupt handler, or an index into an array called an interrupt vector table that contains the memory addresses of interrupt handlers. When an interrupt is generated, the Operating System saves its execution state via a context switch, and begins execution of the interrupt handler at the interrupt vector.

I have some question, i have been searching hardly but no answer yet.

Is the interrupt vector stored at RAM? and if it is stored at RAM, who sets it to ram? the OS?

Answer (score 2):

`interrupt vector is the memory address of an interrupt handler`

memory is synonym to RAM, so yes interrupt vector in stored in the RAM.If a device driver wants to register a interrupt handler function, you need to call appropriate OS calls(incase of linux it is `request_irqs`), and it would create a entry in the Interrupt vector table. This entry would point to wherever you interrupt handler function resides in memory/RAM. **It's the OS that holds the responsibility to manage the interrupt vector table.**

So, whenever that specific interrupt occurs, your interrupt handler function would be called.

Answer (score 2):

It is in the FLASH. Not in the RAM. The registers are in the RAM. Cause the RAM is to store all the data. But the FLASH is to store all the program. And the interrupt vectors are generated by Compiler.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the hardware.

If there's only one address that the CPU can jump to on an interrupt then whether that's ROM or RAM depends on the memory map that the system has built around the CPU. Ditto for a predefined interrupt vector table. If the CPU allows a base address to be set for the interrupt table then it's obviously up to the OS.

Generally speaking, an OS that loads completely from disk — like Windows — will obviously keep it in RAM.

OSes that are stored partly or wholly in ROM generally keep the vector table in RAM so that it can be modified at runtime. On very constrained and well-defined systems like the 8-bit Acorn MOS that's because software might conceivably want to take full control of the hardware — if memory serves then that specific system has the hardware vector in ROM because of the fundamentals of the memory map but puts a routine there that then soft vectors through RAM. So it was a very deliberate decision.

On relatively more spacious systems like the classic Mac OS that's because it allows the ROM to be patched after the fact. If a bug is found in a particular interrupt routine after a machine has shipped then an OS update could be issued that would load a RAM replacement for the routine and just change the vector table. That's especially useful in Mac OS because all calls into the system use a trap mechanism that's analogous to an interrupt.

Answer (score -1):

On the PC under modern windows OS's , the interrupt vectors are stored in the Interrupt Descriptor Table (IDT). You can find out where this table is located using the LIDT instruction (Load Interrupt Descriptor Table).  But you cannot change a value there, unless you can get your code to run in Priviledge Level Zero (ring o), and Microsoft and Intel have conspired to make that almost impossible under Windows, as all instructions which would change the Code Segment Register (CS) to ring 0 are blocked to user programs. That's why WINTEL, like Australopithicus, might prove to be a dead-end in evolutionary terms (I hope).
Basically, PCs are nothing more than a smart terminal; you have to use them just as a terminal on your own machine to do REAL work, like controlling something.